# how to foreach array in MyBatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

this is array:

```
String[] user_login_array={user_email,user_password};
```

this is `mybatis.xml`:

```
<select id="getUser" parameterType="String"resultType="post.User">
     select * from users where user_email=#{user_email} and user_password=#{user_password}
</select>
```

How to add array's parameters to this SQL?

Comment: Do you want to pass the array as an argument to the mapper method? And then use it's elements instead of `user_email` and `user_password` parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something which I got first into mind. Please see the below logic, where you are actually looping over the array and using multiple AND and OR to tackle the query. This may not be the perfect query for you but hope this will give you some insights to the actual solution.

```
<select id="getUser" parameterType="String"resultType="post.User"> 
select * from users where    
          <foreach item="item" collection="user_login_map.entrySet()" separator="OR">
        (user_email=#{item.key} AND user_password=#{item.value})
        </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: Tyvm, and this doesn't work, can't use array for this sql, Map<String,Object> user_login_map =new HashMap<String,Object>();
        user_login_map.put("user_email",user_email);
        user_login_map.put("user_password",user_password);</br>select * from users where user_email = #{user_email} and user_password = #{user_password}</br>doesnt need <foreach>

Comment: The query has just modified to accommodate map. Kindly check.